# Calculate the total occurences of a list values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the numbers of occurrences of list values in a pandas column

```
lst = ['place','wait','ok','amazing','beautiful']
```

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | beautiful place ,me |
| 1 | ok ,good work |
| 2 | wait for me ,ok |
| 2 | amazing place |
| 3 | amazing day |
| 3 | amazing country |
| 3 | amazing world |
| 3 | thank you |

the output should be like

| ID | OCCURENCES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

my solution :

```
df['occurences'] =pd.DataFrame([df['text'].str.count(c) for c in list]).sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the words and use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) intersection for efficiency:

```
lst = ['place','wait','ok','amazing','beautiful']
words = set(lst)

df['OCCURENCES'] = [len(words.intersection(x)) for x in df['TEXT'].str.split('\W+')]
```

output:

```
   ID                  TEXT  OCCURENCES
0    1  beautiful place ,me           2
1    1        ok ,good work           1
2    2      wait for me ,ok           2
3    2        amazing place           2
4    3          amazing day           1
5    3      amazing country           1
6    3        amazing world           1
7    3            thank you           0
```

Comment: @AbderrahimLfilali a set intersection will be much more efficient than `count` in a for loop (which requires to read again and again the string) ;)